# How to make a series of non database methods mimic transactions.

Tags: java, transactions

I have several method calls I need to perform that need to be "transactional" but I am unsure how to implement this aside from try/catch/finally.

**Background**

- Application is console based.
- Application will have multiple threads
- A database is queried for connection information, connection is made to a webservice to login, a session ID is generated and a database is updated.
- An operation invokes a logout, which needs to clean up the database, clear the session ID and log out of the webservice

**What I'm trying to figure out**

I want to make sure that when a logout is requested I want to ensure that the entire process is either all successful, or not at all. For instance I don't want the database to be cleaned up, the session ID cleaned and the logout operation fail (hence the login is still valid).

Ideally the solution would "rollback" on a failure, thereby ensuring the previous state is maintained.

Is there is a slick way to accomplish this, or am I stuck with a series of nested try/catch/finally blocks to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement some `rollback` method, you must store undo data for all the things you'll need to rollback in case of a failure.

- for the DB you already have a rollback method.
- for each file you are modifying/deleting in the operation that may need to be rolled-back, you have to keep a backup copy, to allow you to revert to the previous state.
- any in-memory variables that may have to be rolled-back should have backup copies.

This will allow you at any point in your code to rollback to a previous state when an error occurs.

Comment: that's what I was figuring, essentially the try/catch/finally. Transaction rollback in the database is only good for the database itself, I'll still have to manage all the other states via temp variables.

Comment: Even with DB transactions you need a try/catch/finally block, in order to rollback in the catch and close the connection the the finally. You can reduce the number of such blocks if you throw exceptions in all the places that fail, and catch them at the top level, where you'll call your rollback method. Your finally method can clear all the temp variables/files.

Comment: True. I guess pending any other information I'm going to have to go that route. Ahh well nothing ventured, nothing gained.

Comment: Good answer but I would also clarify the need to consider *deep* copy backups. The rollback feature will get itself into a terrible mess if shallow, mutable references are copied instead. I'd also add (further to comments above) that try/catch/finally is not *inherently* atomic. I've added an example of that amongst the answers.

Answer (score 0):

"neat" might mean something like this ?
(http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html)

but i would much prefer KISS constructs like you mentioned...at least until solidly working before implementing with complex language/resource constructs...make it work...then make it more pretty/fast/decoupled/...

Answer (score 0):

For any casual glancers to this question, **don't** assume that try/catch blocks are inherritently atomic. They're **not**:

**Code proof:**

```
public class TransactionTest {

    private class Thing {
        public int number = 1;
        public String thingName = "Marge";

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TransactionTest();
    }

    public TransactionTest() {
        transactionExperiment();
    }

    private void transactionExperiment() {

        Thing t = new Thing();
        try {
            System.out.println("Original name: " + t.thingName);
            t.thingName = "Homer";
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Throw exception deliberately");
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception");
        }

        System.out.println("Thing is: " + t.thingName);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

- Original name: Marge
- Caught exception
- Thing is: Homer