# Database update command

Tags: mysql, database

if i execute this code:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE MEDICAMENTOS VALUES (47281, 'Ibuprofeno', 'Ben-U-Ron');

UPDATE TABLE MEDICAMENTOS 
SET DESIGNACAO = 'Ibuprofeno Generis'
WHERE CODIGO=47281;
```

So supose that is in transaction A, and after I execute the command update, i execute a transaction B (without a commit in transaction A), the code of transation B is:

```
SELECT designation
FROM MEDICAMENTOS
WHERE CODE BETWEEN ( 10000 AND 90000 );
```

So i'll see "ben-u-ron" because command update does a commit in the past commands, right?

Comment: Both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are in transaction A, so you won't see the new row at all in transaction B.

Comment: But update command do commit when i execute it? Like ddl commands (create, alter, drop)?

Comment: No, `UPDATE` doesn't auto-commit. Only queries that modify the schema.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, that was my question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database transactions - How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466632/database-transactions-how-do-they-work)