# How interdependent db calls handled in transaction.atomic

Tags: mysql, django, transactions, relational-database

I have two DB calls inside the `transaction.atomic()`

Sample codes

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    result1, created = SomeModel.objects.get_or_create(**somedata)
    if not created:
        flag = SomeOtherModel.objects.filter(somemodel=result1).exists()
        if flag:
            result1.some_attr = value1 if flag else value2
            result1.save()
```

AFAIK about the `transaction.atomic` when my python codes do not cause an exception, so all the DB calls will be committed on the database. If any of the exceptions are raised inside the block, no database operation will be committed to the database.

So how is this thing handled when the DB call of one is used in the python logic to make other DB operations?
Didn't find this specific in the documentation, if any good source, please mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Database transactions are a complex topic, I don't have the exact answer with linked documentation but from experience, I can say that you're good to use mutated or new values created within a transaction within the same transaction. The simple explanation for a transaction is it ensures a series of commands either succeed or fail entirely so your database isn't left in a partial in-complete state, in between a transaction your experience with the database at least from an ORM perspective should remain the same.

Here's a good StackOverflow post I found with some good conversations around it: [Database transactions - How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466632/database-transactions-how-do-they-work)